# In-app messenger api with prepopulated text

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, facebook-messenger

Many apps used an in-app Facebook messenger api to share referral link directly to messenger. They also use prepopulated text with a link.

My question is fairly simple : **How do they do it ?**

I could not find any documentation about it, the closest thing I found is the [send dialog api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/) which doesn’t allow any prepopulated text.

Example (Lime app):

[image: Referral page]

[image: Native sharing option (choose messenger)]

[image: In-app Messenger prepopulated text with link]

[image: Linked to messenger]

Answer (score 0):

You need a Link not share, try this package or find something similar
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-facebook-messenger

Comment: Could you add a little more details to your answer and be more specific about the distinction you made between Link and Share? Is the package you linked is the one used by Uber, Limes & other app to share links? Last commit happened 2 years ago and does not seem very known by the community.